# React: формат json-а от backend не позволяет провести рендеринг списком

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть страница, на которой рендерится 10 одинаковых компонентов таблицы с разными данными. Таблица принимает пропсы типа `data, page, perPage` и т.п. и все эти пропсы необходимо хранить в состоянии самой страницы. Сейчас состояние моей страницы выглядит примерно вот так:

```
{
    table1Data: [...],
    table1Page: 1,
    table1PerPage: 10,
    
    table2Data: [...],
    table2Page: 3,
    table2PerPage: 25,
    
    table3Data: [...],
    table3Page: 100,
    table3PerPage: 30,

    ....
}
```

...что мне очень не нравится и архитектурно выглядит ужасно.

**Вопрос:**
Как правильно создавать страницы, на которых планируется рендерить одинаковые компоненты с разными пропсами (данными) при условии что сами данные должны передаваться от родительского компонента?

**Какое решение мне не подходит:** Превратить стейт выше в нечто типа...

```
{
    table1: {
        data: [...],
        page: 1,
        perPage: 10,
    },
    table2: {
        data: [...],
        page: 1,
        perPage: 10,
    },
    table3: {
        data: [...],
        page: 1,
        perPage: 10,
    },
    ...
}
```

Также мне не хочется делать отдельные компоненты из каждой таблицы и хранить состояние в них.

**Какие идеи имею на данный момент:** Сделать что-то типа компонента-обертки, который будет принимать "локальное состояние" в качестве одного из пропсов, а также функции для изменения этого состояние. Например:

```
<LocalState
    state={{
        data: [...],
        page: 1,
        perPage: 10,
    }}
    handlers={(setLocalState) => ({
        setData: () => {...},
        setPage: () => {...},
        setPerPage: () => {...},
    })}
>
    {(state, handlers) => <Table {...state} {...handlers} />}
</LocalState>
```

В общем, подскажите, как бы вы решили такую проблему и как по-вашему архитектурно правильно ее решать?

Comment: Ранее я писал рекурсивный компонент для рендеринга форм, если стоит задача отрендерить представление в ui по json-шаблону, возможно, вам будет интересно...

https://github.com/tripolskypetr/material-ui-umd/blob/master/packages/form-generator-app/src/pages/one.tsx#L27

Answer (score 2):

А почему бы просто не превратить одно в другое, к чему такие сложности?

> Адаптер — структурный шаблон проектирования, предназначенный для организации использования функций объекта, недоступного для модификации, через специально созданный интерфейс.

[image: screenshot]

```
(function() {

  const capitalize = (s) => s[0].toUpperCase() + s.slice(1);

  const wrap = (obj) => Object.entries(obj)
    .reduce((acm, [key, v]) => Object.entries(v)
      .map(([k, v]) => [capitalize(k), v])
        .reduce((acm, [k, v]) =>  ({...acm, [key + k]: v}), acm), 
  {});

  console.log(wrap({
    table1: {
      data: ['...'],
      page: 1,
      perPage: 10,
    },
    table2: {
      data: ['...'],
      page: 1,
      perPage: 10,
    },
    table3: {
      data: ['...'],
      page: 1,
      perPage: 10,
    },
  }));

})();
```

Соответственно, то же преобразование, но в обратную сторону

[image: screenshot]

```
(function() {

  const lowerize = (s) => s[0].toLowerCase() + s.slice(1);

  const getProp = (str) => {
    const {index} = /[A-Z]/g.exec(str);
    return [str.slice(0, index), lowerize(str.slice(index, str.length))];
  };

  const unwrap = (obj) => Object.entries(obj)
    .reduce((acm, [k, v]) => {
      const [key, prop] = getProp(k);
      if (key in acm) {
        acm[key][prop] = v;
      } else {
        acm[key] = {};
        acm[key][prop] = v;
      }
      return acm;
    }, {})

  console.log(unwrap({
    table1Data: ['...'],
    table1Page: 1,
    table1PerPage: 10,
    table2Data: ['...'],
    table2Page: 3,
    table2PerPage: 25,
    table3Data: ['...'],
    table3Page: 100,
    table3PerPage: 30,
  }));

})();
```

Comment: Ответ безусловно полезный — апвойт, но сама такая структура приложения — костыль. Все это плохо масштабируется, ведь таблиц может быть не 10, а 100 и тогда это превратится в какое-то засорения пространства имен состояния.